# ajax response return html response (XSS veracode)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

```
function viewAcc() {
    var errorMsg = "";
    var result = true;
    $(".errorView").hide();
    var accNum = document.getElementById('custAccNum').value;
    var accType = document.getElementById('custAccType').value;
    $("#overlayPopup").show();
    $.ajax({
        url : '<attribute:resourceURL/>',
        data : {
            "custNo" : accNum ,
            "custType" : accType 
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if (data == 'CUS_ACC') {
                window.location = "/cust/account/c";
            } else {
                $("#overlayPopup").hide();
                //display warning
                $(".errorView").show();
                $(".errorView").html(data); // <--- XSS line
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        cache : false,
        dataType : 'text',
        error : function(error, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error in ajax call: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('error in ajax call: ' + textStatus);
            window.location = "/cust/account/c/lookup";
        },
        timeout : ajaxTimeOutMilliSeconds
    });

}
```

So the veracode point out says I have issue on `$(".errorView").html(data);` 
How do I fix this? If I just make it to text will it show on the client as is with the html?

Comment: find a way to not need .html(). That can be done by having the server return text, and then the client wraps that text in html.

Comment: you mean make `data` into text? but isnt data already text?

Comment: idunno, you tell me. it can be text, xml, json, many things that can be represented by a string. If it's just text with no html, no html entites, etc, you can swap to .text with no downsides.

Comment: ` $(".errorView").text(data);`  is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) instead of [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). If you don't have any markup coming from the server, then this is a perfectly viable alternative, since `.text()` will prevent the content being interpreted as HTML

```js
//doing sc+ript is only needed here because Stack Snippets otherwise throws an error.
var msg = "This is <b>a message</b> with <script>console.log('some code')</sc"+"ript>";
$("#msgHtml").html(msg);
$("#msgText").text(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Message via .html():</h3>
<div id="msgHtml"></div>

<h3>Message via .text():</h3>
<div id="msgText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't blindly trust tools which claim you are vulnerable to XSS.

You are only at risk of XSS if the value of `data` is not trustworthy. Since it is coming from your own server, then you should have already sanitised the data for XSS issues before sending it in the response to the Ajax request.

Comment: then how am I suppose to remed veracode ? I cannot just tell security team to ignore it.

Comment: Why not? It's a false positive.

Comment: Well, either a false positive or a problem with the server side code at `<attribute:resourceURL/>`.

Comment: "*Since it is coming from your own server*" that's not a good criteria for trustworthyness. You can definitely have a "malicious server" scenario. You might decide not to do anything at this point but that should be a conscious decision, not a given. *Any* data you get from an AJAX call might have been tampered with. In fact, I very frequently do that during development - I'd do a userscript which loads up mockJax and spoofs some endpoints. If an attacker can control the data being send and received, you're in danger.

Comment: @VLAZ — If your own server is malicious then you need to fix your server. The problem isn't with the client side code.

Comment: A "malicious server" scenario is when it *isn't* your own server sending you data back.

Comment: @VLAZ — All indications are that it is a relative URL, so it is the same server as the one hosting the HTML document.

Comment: And yet I already provided an example where a server wouldn't be returning me the data. This proves that a call *even to a relative URL* can be intercepted and modified. I don't need to enumerate every single possible way for this to happen to prove it's possible.

Comment: @VLAZ — The user is in complete control of their own browser. It isn't an XSS attack if they install a user script to change the way the site works. There are easier ways for them to execute JS in their own browser.

Comment: There could be a vulnerabilty to the browser, a vulnerability in an addon, or an actually malicious addon that is subtle. Moreover, content can be served through malicious proxies the user can otherwise fall victim to a MITM. Again, my point stands - the data you send or receive is not guaranteed to be exactly what you expect. Yes, sometimes the security warnings can be bogus but if mitigating them takes literally four bytes, I don't see value in discarding them. It takes MORE EFFORT justifying this isn't a threat *and* you need to keep doing it periodically.

Comment: @VLAZ — If there is a vulnerability in the browser which allows arbitrary JS execution then it would be silly for them to use a remote execution vulnerability to modify a website in a browser so that they could inject data which would be a remote execution vulnerability.

Comment: @VLAZ — And mitigating it doesn't take 4 bytes: Using `text()` instead of `html()` would stop the HTML returned from the server being rendered.

Comment: I am not convinced the answer to "this could be a security issue" is "but *might* not be". But I'll leave it here because apparently proving it could be an issue isn't enough.

Comment: @VLAZ — There isn't a security issue with the code here. There might be a security issue with the server side code, but that needs to be addressed on the server. As I said already.

Comment: It should be addressed on the server, but there's no reason not to make a simple change with no consequences to protect the client in the event the server has a bug or is otherwise compromised.

Comment: Using `text()` instead of `html()` would stop the HTML returned from the server being rendered.